# Delphi RAD Server - write Log Server Console to files by Date

Tags: delphi, logging, ems

I am currently using RAD Server in my project and adding "Append" and "FileName" fields to my emsserver.ini. This method can help to save to a file but everything is save to 1 file. I wanted to save its log file to a specific path by date so that I can easily track and locate the logs. Is there any way to achieve this?